# Reading first name and last name of users from entity object in Drupal 8

Tags: drupal-8

I can use getUsername() method to fetch username of a particular user (not current user) in Drupal 8 controller like following

```
        $other_id = $message->user_id ;
        $other_user_object = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load($other_id );
        $name = $other_user_object ->getUsername();
```

Here username is stored in my data_field table. getUsername() method allows me to fetch the data without mentioning table and column name. Now I want to fetch first_name and last_name of that particular user which are stored in users_data_more table. Is there any method in Drupal 8 to fetch the data? if not, how to fetch those data in Drupal 8 controller ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can get the other values by accessing those variables value as below:

```
if (isset($other_user_object->field_first_name)) {
  $first_name = $other_user_object->field_first_name->value;
}
if (isset($other_user_object->field_last_name)) {
  $last_name = $other_user_object->field_last_name->value;
}
```

Assuming your field names are `field_first_name` and `field_last_name`

Comment: not working, it says 'field_first_name' not found in /Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityInterface

Comment: also giving this message in the page Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in Drupal\mod\Controller\myController->show()

Comment: Whats your field's machine name? `~/admin/config/people/accounts/fields` Look for the MACHINE NAME to corresponding First Name and Last Name fields. Also confirm value is present in that fields for corresponding user

Comment: i found the machine names of the fields from ~admin/config/people/accounts/fields . those fields have data in the database. but it is showing same message

Comment: What are the field machine names?

Answer (score 1):

To know fields, there is :  `$user->getFields();` function.

So in my case :

```
$user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(\Drupal::currentUser()->id());
if ($user->isAuthenticated()) {
    $form['custom_first_name']['#value'] = $user->get('field_first_name')->getString();
    $form['name']['#value'] = $user->get('field_last_name')->getString();
}
```

`Guys : Don't forget :     var_dump(get_class_methods($object));   to discover quickly tools you have.`